# How can I speed up the training of a network using my GPU?

Tags: python, neural-network, gpu, pybrain

I was wondering if there is a way to use my GPU to speed up the training of a network in PyBrain.

Answer (score 2):

Unless PyBrain is designed for that, you probably can't.

You might want to try running your trainer under PyPy if you aren't already -- it's significantly faster than CPython for some workloads. Perhaps this is one of those workloads. :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Pylearn2: https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2

It's a newer library and can run on GPU's with CUDA via cuda-convnet.